# Can we use Oauth for our application?

Tags: oauth

I have a question about a project we are creating. Here are some basic use cases:

- A user can register and edit their company details (and other details) online
- A user is member of one or more user groups (a user group is a company)
- Data groups can contain multiple companies (eg. a group called 'Amsterdam' contains all companies from Amsterdam)

The data that is stored in the database can be used for touchscreens to show visitors these details (eg. company details from 'Amsterdam' and 'The Hague'). So some use cases can be defined as:

- A touchscreen can download data from one or more datagroups
- Api keys are defined at the user group not at the user, if a user is fired they shouldn't be able to get the data anymore

But now the biggest question. 
Can we use Oauth (which version I don't care) to download the data to the touchscreens AND can we use Oauth so that users can login to the online controlpanel?

Can we write the controlpanel as an Oauth application to the datastore backend? Or does the control panel need to be an Oauth independent application so users can create applications or we (as administrators) can create new applications for each touchscreen?

I have already read some about Oauth and I understand the basic principles, but I don't know if it is the best solution for the above use cases.